# Spring Boot Cloud SQL IAM service account authentication In GKE

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, spring-data-jpa, google-cloud-sql

My application works fine most of the time in GCP's K8's but the weird thing is from time to time it is starts to throw connection not available errors, even though many connections are available. DB connections are set to couple of thousands but not even 1000 has been reached so far. Application is using IAM authentication using service account and is small enough and below are some of the details.

**Note:** I am of course omitting some details due to sensitivity.

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://google/mydb?cloudSqlInstance=myInstance&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory&enableIamAuth=true
spring.datasource.username=myserviceaccount@project.iam
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=200
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=30
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=60000
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=10000
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=10000
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
                <version>20.7.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2020.0.4</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-release</id>
            <name>Spring release</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
   <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-release</id>
            <name>Spring release</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgres-socket-factory</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

**Errors**

```
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 28000
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Pool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 60001ms.
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : FATAL: Cloud SQL IAM service account authentication failed for user "myserviceaccount@project.iam"
```

Once that exception occurs I am deleting that pod and recreating it, which fixes for time being. Though it's weird that recreating pod uses same authentication which works afterwards. Any help or pointer will be appreciated.

**Update:**

Upgraded `postgres-socket-factory` to `1.8.3` but still getting same issue.

**Update 2:**

Upgraded `postgres-socket-factory` to `1.9.0` but still getting same issue.

Comment: I suggest contacting a paid support for your GCP project to investigate your project, cluster and deployments, to escalate more deeply.

Comment: What version of the socket factory are you using? There was a recent bug in the underlying OAuth2 library that we fixed recently that you might be hitting here.

Comment: I was using 1.7.2 . My DB is Cloud SQL postgres. Today I upgraded it to 1.8.3 but still I got this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @jan-hoeve. I also noticed these issues on gcp side few days ago and then I updated socket factory version but the problem was the latest socket factory driver was still using `0.26` version of auth library from gcp which as you pointed out has that issue. So I updated below two libraries as well after which I am not getting any issues so far.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgres-socket-factory</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.auth</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-auth-library-oauth2-http</artifactId>
            <version>1.15.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.auth</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-auth-library-credentials</artifactId>
            <version>1.15.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I already got this postgres-socket-factory:1.9.0 in via com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-postgresql:4.0.0 but the other two libs were transitively set to 1.14.0.
So I just bumped these two to 1.15.0 ... let's see how it works out!

But note that it could take hours until the error pops up again ;)

Comment: Update: it still throws errors, we might be looking at the wrong side of things with these dependency changes, since I notice these errors are coming from PostgreSQL itself. Go to Cloud SQL / "View PostgreSQL error logs" (at the bottom) and read the errors.

Comment: Update 2: since the IAM based auth turns out to be unreliable, I switched back to good (?) old username/password auth. No issues so far :) 
Note that you can do it securely by putting the password into the GCP secretmanager and use 'sm://' to fetch it. https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-spring-cloud-gcp-secret-manager#4

Comment: weird, you seems to be true as I saw it today on dev but not so far on prod. Unfortunately we can't switch to user/pass but point taken. I will keep an eye on this.

Comment: Any news for this issue?

Comment: upgrading auth libraries, reduced amount of connection issues I was facing.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and after contacting GCP support they pointed me to a new version of the Oauth2 lib like said above, version 1.12.1
https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java/pull/1031

It works indeed, but in my case the issue resurfaced with newer versions.
It also happens again with this said 1.12.1 Oauth2 lib, but with *other* deps increased, like the socket factory. But YMMV :)

In my case the issue pops up once or twice during 24H, but when it happens, it complains for e.g. 10 minutes straight. And indeed, killing a pod 'helps'.